# how to margin or padding in option select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

how to margin or padding option select

I used `&nbsp;`

```html
<select class="select">
   <option value="100"></option>
   <option value="250">$593</option>
   <option value="500">$1125</option>
   <option value="1000">$2125</option>
   <option value="2000">$3750</option>
   <option value="3000">$5250</option>
   <option value="5000">$6250</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: What plugin are you using for the select? That will help lots in finding a good solution for you. Also please include what you have tried

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen this is one of the most asked questions on SO, why would you re-opened the question ??

Comment: depends on the lib to show the select, just set css style "select { text-align:right; } if it is native browser select tag

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/W6zXiY5.png

Comment: I want it to the sides

Comment: @dippas while yes it's not possible to style a normal select/option, but from the image it's clearly a plugin/library the OP is using. So if we got the name of that It would maybe be possible to actually assist here.

Comment: @PhungThuan Please inform us about what plugin/library you are using

Comment: Use a fixed-width font and space it out

Comment: I don't know if my answer fits your question. if not please explain more to try to help you out.

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution with manipulating in padding, indent and margin.

```css
select {
    margin: 6px;
    font: 16px Arial;
}
select {
    width: 262px;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 4px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-indent: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<select class="select">
   <option value="100"></option>
   <option value="250">$593</option>
   <option value="500">$1125</option>
   <option value="1000">$2125</option>
   <option value="2000">$3750</option>
   <option value="3000">$5250</option>
   <option value="5000">$6250</option>
</select>
```